# Error al subir app en HEROKU, npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

Tags: nodejs, npm, heroku, packages

estoy intentando subir mi app en HEROKU pero tengo este problema ya no doy con la solucion..

precisamente me da un error con el paquete bcrypt, el mismo fue desintalado e instalado el bcryptjs y se actualizo en la libreria, en el package.json pero aun me da error de la libreria desintalada.

He leido muchos metodos que el install --save del bcryptjs y el desintalar el bcrypt, pero por lo que observan no tengo el package.json ese paquete....

```
emote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:        
remote:        > bcrypt@5.0.0 install /tmp/build_f732b199/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.0 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.0suMV/_logs/2021-01-30T23_05_05_869Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Aqui esta el PACKAGE.JSON.

```
{
  "name": "api-rest-nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Api Rest del master de Javascript",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.14",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.14",
    "node-gyp": "^7.1.2",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.17.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.4.1",
    "validator": "^13.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos, lo que hice fue instalar el repositorio de node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build en el powershell y esto me soluciono el problema con heroku, Ahora tengo otro! pero ya se solvento esta hilo...

Answer (score 0):

he tenido ese problema trabajando de forma local cuando hago pull del repositorio remoto, siempre me funciona eliminar la carpeta node_modules, el archivo package-lock.json y ejecutar de nuevo el npm install, en tu caso asegurate ademas que la carpeta node_modules esta incluida en el gitignore ya que estas subiendo la app a un servidor.